# if user login show **logintemplate ` in meteor otherwise show `index template`?

Tags: meteor

if user login show **logintemplate** in meteor otherwise show **index template**.I want when user login show the after login page it is ok .But i am asking when we are give at web url afterlogin template like(/admin) it will open i want when ever we give /admin show the home page not showing admin page.plz suggest me.

Comment: Please try to explain more, I have a hard time understanding what you need. Please also include some code.

Comment: Check `Meteor.userId` for the user being logged in? If you use iron-router you can do this per route like in onBeforeAction callback.

Comment: After login show the profile template .Example www.myapp.com in that url we are type like this www.myapp/profile it show the profile page i am using iron-router but i want if we give www.myapp/profile show the please login and go to login page@below9k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking this.

**With JSCode.**

```
Router.route('/', function () {
 if(Meteor.userId(){
     this.render('loginTemplate'); 
    }else{
     this.render('login')
   }
});
```

**Using Spacebars**.

```
{{#if currentUser}}
  {{> loginTemplate}}
{{else}}
  {{> login}}
{{/if}}
```

**Using onBeforeAction**

**First** The function

```
var requireLogin = function() {
  if (! Meteor.user()) {
    if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
      this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
    } else {
      this.render('accessDenied');
    }
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
}
```

**Second**  onBeforeAction

```
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: 'loginTemplate'}); // this will only been applied to the `loginTemplate`.
```

Comment: Thanq for help@Ethaan

Comment: Hi  it is working and one more thing is if we click back button on browser profile page is came how to solve.@Ethaan

Comment: Sorry i don't get it.. when the user click back on the browser what happened?

Comment: Browser buttons at the top after logout from the app click back button again display the previous page.@Ethaan

Comment: what of the 3 options are you using?

Comment: 3 options means i didn't understand@Ethaan